# Construct a new variable with R

Tags: r

I've a data frame (call it Output) with two variables (x: binary, and y:factor with 6 levels and NA). Here are the first few observations:

```
x    y
0   x4
0   Group3 or Group4
1   <NA>
0   x1
1   x2
0   Group3
1   x3
1   Group3 or Group4
1   x1
1   Group3
0   <NA>
```

I'm trying to construct a new variable (let's call it wn) that if x=1 and y="Group3 or Group4" then wn="Group4", else keep the same value as in y.

I tried the following code, but what I'm getting is not right. Any help will be appreciated.

```
wn <- ifelse((Output$x == 1) & (Output$y == "Group3 or Group4"), "Group4",Output$y)

data.frame(Output$x,Output$y,wn)
```

Comment: What do you get? And what is not right? Are there integer numbers in `wn`? Indicates `class(Output$y) that this is a `factor`? You should then cast `Output$y <- as.character(Output$y)`. Oh und you can directly add the column to the existing `data.frame` with `Output$wn <- ifelse(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifelse` is giving you the factor code for `y`. You'll need to coerce it to `character` before assigning it:

```
ifelse(...., "Group4", as.character(Output$y))
```